# Having trouble splitting and merging memory blocks: linked list segfaulting

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, merge, split

I'm building my own memory allocator and my programs are segfaulting because of my splitting ( when a block is allocated, splitting into two block one with data allocated and one with the rest of the free memory not used) and of my merging ( merging neighbor free memory slots ) and I just can't figure out where the problem ism any help is appreciated.

Here is my splitting method:

```
struct mem_block *split_block(struct mem_block *block, size_t size)
{

if(block->free){
    char *block_address = (char *)block;
    struct mem_block *second_block = (struct mem_block *)(block_address + size);
    second_block->size = block->size - size;
    block->size = size;
    second_block->region_id = block->region_id;
    snprintf(second_block->name, 32, "Allocation: %lu\n", g_allocations++);

    if(block->next != NULL){
        second_block->next = block->next;
        second_block->prev = block;
        block->next = second_block;
    }
    else{
        block->next = second_block;
        second_block->prev = block;
        second_block->next = NULL;
        g_tail = second_block;
   }
   LOG("Split completed; old block address = %p, new block address = %p\n", block, second_block);
   return second_block;
}
else{
    return NULL;
}
}
```

Here is my merging method:

```
struct mem_block *merge_block(struct mem_block *block)
{
if(g_head == NULL && g_tail == NULL){
    block->next = NULL;
    block->prev = NULL;

    g_head = block;
    g_tail = block;
    return g_head;
}
else {
    g_tail->next = block;
    block->prev = g_tail;
    block->next = NULL;
    g_tail = block;
    return g_tail;
}
return NULL;
}
```

Here is my memory block structure:

```
struct mem_block {
/**
 * The name of this memory block. If the user doesn't specify a name for the
 * block, it should be auto-generated based on the allocation ID. The format
 * should be 'Allocation X' where X is the allocation ID.
 */
char name[32];

/** Size of the block */
size_t size;

/** Whether or not this block is free */
bool free;

/**
 * The region this block belongs to.
 */
unsigned long region_id;

/** Next block in the chain */
struct mem_block *next;

/** Previous block in the chain */
struct mem_block *prev;

/**
 * "Padding" to make the total size of this struct 100 bytes. This serves no
 * purpose other than to make memory address calculations easier. If you
 * add members to the struct, you should adjust the padding to compensate
 * and keep the total size at 100 bytes; test cases and tooling will assume
 * a 100-byte header.
 */
char padding[35];
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Here is the malloc function where split is called:

```
void *malloc(size_t size)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&alloc_mutex);
size_t total_size = size + sizeof(struct mem_block);
size_t aligned_size = total_size;
if (total_size % 8 !=0) {
    aligned_size = (total_size / 8) * 8 + 8;
}

LOG("Allocation: request size = %zu, total size = %zu, aligned size = %zu\n", 
size, total_size, aligned_size);

struct mem_block *reused_block = reuse(aligned_size);
if(reused_block != NULL){
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
    return reused_block + 1;
}

int page_size = getpagesize();
size_t num_pages = aligned_size / page_size;
if(aligned_size % page_size != 0){
    num_pages++;
}
size_t region_size = num_pages * page_size;

struct mem_block *block = mmap(NULL, region_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, 
MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

if(block == MAP_FAILED){
    perror("mmap");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
    return NULL;
}
snprintf(block->name, 32, "Allocation %lu", g_allocations++);
block->size = region_size;
block->free = true;
block->region_id = g_regions++;
LOG("Name: %s\n", block->name);
if(g_head == NULL && g_tail == NULL){
    block->next = NULL;
    block->prev = NULL;
    g_head = block;
    g_tail = block;
}
else {
    g_tail->next = block;
    block->prev = g_tail;
    block->next = NULL;
    g_tail = block;
}

split_block(block, aligned_size);
block->free = false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
return block+1;
}
```

Here is the free function where merge is called:

```
void free(void *ptr)
{
pthread_mutex_lock(&alloc_mutex);
LOG("Free request; address = %p\n", ptr);

if (ptr == NULL) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
    return;
}

struct mem_block *block = (struct mem_block *) ptr-1;

block->free = true;

if(block->prev != NULL){
    block->prev->next = block->next;
}
if(block->next != NULL){
    block->next->prev = block->prev;
}
if(g_head == block){
    g_head = block->next;
}

if(g_tail == block){
    g_tail = block->prev;
}

int ret = munmap(block, block->size);
if (ret == -1){
    perror("munmap");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
    return;
}

merge_block(block);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&alloc_mutex);
return;
}
```

Comment: This needs a proper [mcve]. You also need to illuminate the mystery of where/how in the split function do you determine the free block you're splitting is actually large enough to split to `size` and and have space remaining. I.e. What happens when the `block->size <= size` is true, and what do you do to account for that? The offsets of those members also look like they could/would easily clash. I.e. small enough block split could put `block->size` and `second_block->region_id` in the same memory ,which is obviously a catastrophe in the making. Regardless, [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am adding the memory block structure, the malloc function where split is called ( after a memory block has been allocated ) and the free function where merge is called ( after memory has been freed to have only one big free block instead of multiple ).